# Kohana 3.x ORM paradigm and MVC concept

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana, kohana-orm

One thing I discovered in Kohana 3.x concerned the ORM and the MVC. In fact, far away in the ORM section I can read basic examples in controller. Where calls on databases are made, modified and saved directly to the database...This does not value the MVC concept.

```
class Controller_User extends Controller {
    function action_register() {
    $user = ORM::factory('User')
    ->values($this->input->post())
    ->save();
    }
}
```

They could have done this in their documentation

```
class Model_user extends ORM {
function register($array) {
return ORM::factory('User')->values($array)->save();
}
}
```

And simply call the *Model::register($array)* from the Controller.

I think to best practice resides in the useful of MVC. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I always put functions which I know I am going to use more than exactly one time in the Model, and stuff that will only happen on one place (e.g. user registration) in another. Besides, what about this thing specifically designed for user authetication? http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#create_user

Comment: Well .. yes, Kohana does not implement MVC (or anything even vaguely resembling MVC pattern). It is much closer to Rails-like pattern. You might find this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uV3ngl1Z8g) as a good starting point for beginning a shift towards MVC.

Comment: Yes @tereško it is not useful to think about MVC while working on Kohana it is useless. They even check the Validation submitting in Models instead of in Controller. I think I will focus on the documentation to move forward. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kohana documentation often shows the quickest way to get results not necessarily the best way.

Best practice is really something you have to figure out for yourself by reading forums and blogs.  One persons idea of best practice may not be another's.

Personally I agree with you and have thin controllers and do all the heavy lifting in the model but I'm sure many people would tell me I'm doing it all wrong ;-)

Comment: I am trying to focus on doing every thing in the controller and form validation in Model. This is keeping my code very clean and the next developer in the same work may also fit well later. Thanks for your contribution.